# Please help me understand the code

Tags: java

I unable to understand the following code snippet:

```
List<? extends Number> intList = Collections.nCopies(5, new Integer(10));
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

objList.add(new Object());

}

Collections.copy(objList, intList);

System.out.println("The objList is: " + objList);
```

The declaration of the copy method:

```
static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src);
```

I understand that by `List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();` and `objList.add(new Object());` lines Object is replacing both T and ? and since the declaration of the copy method stipulates that its first parameter should be the super class of T and unlike `extends`, `super` is exclusive clause so ? and T must not be the same, I don't see it's a valid code. 
It could have been more like this:

```
List<Integer> objList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); (but it gives compilation error.
```

Then how this code is working? Could you please explain?

Comment: From where did you read that `super` is exclusive?

Comment: Code works due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: List<Object> is not super-type of List<Integer> or any other type for that matter. If a variable is declared List<Object> your are supposed to stash just that not List<Integer>, not List<String>. The Generics part of the SUN Tutorial explains why.

Comment: I found it in Java Complete Reference book's Generics chapter: "You can also specify a lower bound for a wildcard by adding a super clause to a wildcard declaration. Here is its general form: <? super subclass> In this case, only classes that are super classes of subclass are acceptable arguments. This is an exclusive clause, because it will not match the class specified by subclass."

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to your understanding, the super relationship is reflexive, (so, for all T, T is a super type of T).

Thus a satisfying type for copy is:

```
void copy(List<Object>, List<Number>)
```

since Number extends Object, and Object is a super type of Object.

This is explained a bit in this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html